# Ways of sending parameters to static kerenel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I could find module_param to send parameters for kernel module ( loadable module i guess). Is this module_param can be used to send parameters to static modules( compiled with kerenel).

Please let me know, ways of **defining** and  **sending** parameters for static module. ( more details if possible )
I do appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modules built into the kernel image, add your module-custom parameters to the kernel boot params list.  This list will (depending on architecture) be passed by the bootloader or built into the kernel.

It will look something like this:

```
mymod.fooparam=debug
```

For reference, see the [kernel-params documentation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt).

You define the parameters in the module the same way you would for a dynamically loaded module.

edit:  This is from: `arch/arm/Kconfig`
You can set the cmdline via the .config file that is generated based on build options.

```
config CMDLINE
        string "Default kernel command string"
        default ""
        help
          On some architectures (EBSA110 and CATS), there is currently no way
          for the boot loader to pass arguments to the kernel. For these
          architectures, you should supply some command-line options at build
          time by entering them here. As a minimum, you should specify the
          memory size and the root device (e.g., mem=64M root=/dev/nfs).

choice
        prompt "Kernel command line type" if CMDLINE != ""
        default CMDLINE_FROM_BOOTLOADER

config CMDLINE_FROM_BOOTLOADER
        bool "Use bootloader kernel arguments if available"
        help
          Uses the command-line options passed by the boot loader. If
          the boot loader doesn't provide any, the default kernel command
          string provided in CMDLINE will be used.

config CMDLINE_EXTEND
        bool "Extend bootloader kernel arguments"
        help
          The command-line arguments provided by the boot loader will be
          appended to the default kernel command string.

config CMDLINE_FORCE
        bool "Always use the default kernel command string"
        help
          Always use the default kernel command string, even if the boot
          loader passes other arguments to the kernel.
          This is useful if you cannot or don't want to change the
          command-line options your boot loader passes to the kernel.
endchoice
```

Comment: Any idea how arm is doing this ?:

Comment: @Thannerusrinivas I've seen this done more than one way on ARM, IIRC.  One way is via the `make menuconfig` and the other make variants.  Another is to maintain a bootconfig string in the source tree where the board-specific init code is maintained.  I'll take a look at the codeaurora.org (Android) code and post another comment if I find something specific.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  There may be other ways to do this under `arch/arm/<arch>/<board>`, but I would start with setting the boot params via the config menu.